Dealing with interlacing lock in Python3
I am trying to implement the following logic in Python3:
# Clarification:
# function f() is the only function that would acquire both locks
# It is protected by other locks so f() itself has no concurrency.
# It always acquires lock1 first and then acquire lock2 inside lock1
# In other words, NO thread will own lock2 and wait for lock1

def f():

  lock1.acquire()

  task_protected_by_lock1() # Might acquire lock2 internally

  lock2.acquire()

  task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2()

  lock1.release()

  task_protected_by_lock2() # Might acquire lock1 internally

  lock2.release()

However, I found it impossible to correctly handle SIGINT because it will raise a KeyBoardInterrupt exception at random location. I need to guarantee that lock1 and lock2 are both released when control flow exits f() (i.e. either normal return or unhandled exception).
I am aware that SIGINT can be temporarily masked. However, correctly restoring the mask becomes another challenge because it might already been masked from outside. Also, the tasks performed between locks might also tweak signal masks. I believe there has to be a better solution.
I am wondering if there exist a way for me to utilize context-manager (with statement) to achieve it. I've considered the following, but none would work for my use case:
Approach 1 - single with statement
def f():
  with lock1, lock2:
    task_protected_by_lock1() # Bad: acquiring lock2 internally will cause deadlock
    task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2() # Good
    task_protected_by_lock2() # Bad: acquiring lock1 internally will cause deadlock

Approach 2 - nested with statement
def f():
  with lock1:
    task_protected_by_lock1() # Good
    with lock2:
      task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2() # Good
      task_protected_by_lock2() # Bad: acquiring lock1 internally will cause deadlock

Approach 3 - manual lock management
def f():

  flag1 = False
  flag2 = False

  try:
    lock1.acquire()
    # Bad: SIGINT might be raised here
    flag1 = True

    task_protected_by_lock1()

    lock2.acquire()
    # Bad: SIGINT might be raised here
    flag2 = True

    task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2()

    lock1.release()
    # Bad: SIGINT might be raised here
    flag1 = False

    task_protected_by_lock2()

    lock2.release()
    # Bad: SIGINT might be raised here
    flag2 = False

  except Exception as e:

    if flag1:
      lock1.release()

    if flag2:
      lock2.release()

    raise e

Approach 4 - similar to 3, but trickier
def f():
  try:
    lock1.acquire()

    task_protected_by_lock1()

    lock2.acquire()

    task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2()

    lock1.release()

    # Suppose SIGINT happened here, just after another thread acquired lock1

    task_protected_by_lock2()

    lock2.release()

  except Exception as e:

    if lock1.locked():
      lock1.release() # Bad: lock1 is NOT owned by this thread!

    if lock2.locked():
      lock2.release()

    raise e

Approach 5 - breaks consistency & inefficient
def f():
  with lock1:
    task_protected_by_lock1()

  # Bad: other thread might acquire lock1 and modify protected resources.
  # This breaks data consistency between 1st and 2nd task.

  with lock1, lock2:
    task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2()

  # Bad: other thread might acquire lock2 and modify protected resources.
  # This breaks data consistency between 2nd and 3rd task.

  with lock2:
    task_protected_by_lock2()

Update: Pseudo code demonstrating why I need interlacing lock
Here is the logic I am trying to implement. This logic is part of a utility library, therefore the behavior of task() is dependent how user implements it.
You're welcome to provide a better solution that does not require interlacing lock while retaining the exact same behavior.
lock1 = Lock() # Guards observation/assignment of `task`
lock2 = Lock() # Guards        execution       of `task`

# Executing it might acquire lock1 and change `task`
task: callable | Generator

def do_task():
  lock1.acquire()

  if not validate_task(task):
    task = None # `task` can be modified here

  if task is None:
    # observation of task fails
    return lock1.release()

  lock2.acquire() # Execution lock acquired before observation lock released

  task_snapshot = task

  lock1.release() # Now other process may update `task`,
                  # But since execution lock (lock2) is owned here,
                  # updated task will not be executed till this one finishes.

  try:
    if callable(task_snapshot):
      task_snapshot()
    else:
      assert isinstance(task_snapshot, Generator)
      # This is why lock2 is needed.
      # Concurrent next() will throw "generator already executing"
      next(task_snapshot)
  except:
    with lock1:
      task = None

  lock2.release()


Desired pattern (suppose the 2nd execution of task1 updates the task):
task1, task1, task1, task2, task2, ....


Bad pattern (suppose the same scenario as above):
task1, task1, /task2/, task1, task2, ....




There's usually a design problem of some kind if you need to acquire and release locks in a non-nested fashion. So this seems like an XY problem

You can use the signal.pthread_sigmask function. Something like orig = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, [SIGINT]) and later in a finally block, pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, orig). Could even wrap it in a context manager for ease of use

Trying to handle KeyboardInterrupt is futile: it can be raised basically at any point and can break your invariants. Either replace SIGINT handler or stop caring about broken invariants by letting KeyboardInterrupt propagate and terminate the process (perhaps gracefully). This is equally true for single-threaded code.

If thread A is executing the 1st task, it holds the lock1. It may move on to the 2nd task only if it acquires also the lock2. If - in the same time - thread B is executing the 3rd task, it holds the lock2 and - according to the comment - it might acquire the lock1 internally. What does it exactly mean "it might"? If the thread B needs that lock1, it must wait for the thread A, but thread A cannot continue without the lock2 held by the waiting thread B (a deadlock). Or am I missing something?

I see: I left out a critical presumption in my own code: f() itself is not concurrent. I've updated the question and clarified it.

One other possibility is to replace the locks with reentrant locks. Then it doesn't matter if you lock them twice, so you can lock them both at once in an outer context manager (your “approach 1”).

You can interleave context managers by using contextlib.ExitStack, with a "stack" of just one context manager, because it lets you exit it early with the close() method:
with ExitStack() as es:
    es.enter_context(lock_a)
    protected_by_a()
    with lock_b:
        protected_by_a_and_b()
        es.close()
        protected_by_b()

You can even push more context managers back on to it after close() if need be, allowing you to do more complex things:
with ExitStack() as es_a:
    with ExitStack() as es_b:
        es_a.enter_context(lock_a)
        es_b.enter_context(lock_b)
        protected_by_a_and_b()
        es_b.close()
        protected_by_a()
        es_b.enter_context(lock_b)
        protected_by_a_and_b()
        es_a.close()
        protected_by_b()

You can even pass the exit stack objects as parameters to other functions for them to close and relock. But then it's up to you to debug the deadlocks in the monster you've created!

My own update:
I found an approach that theoretically conforms to my need:
Approach 6 - works, but induces unnecessary lock operations:
class ReleaseLock:
  def __init__(self, lock: Lock):
    self.lock = lock

  def __enter__(self):
    return self.lock.release()

  def __exit__(self, *_):
    self.lock.acquire()


def f():
  with lock1, lock2:
    # Bad: extra lock2.acquire()

    with ReleaseLock(lock2):
      # Bad: extra lock2.release()
      task_protected_by_lock1()

    task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2()

    with ReleaseLock(lock1):
      task_protected_by_lock2()
      # Bad: extra lock1.acquire()

   # Bad: extra lock1.release()

Additional thoughts:
I think the root cause of this trouble is that python does not allow interlacing managed contexts due to how its code is organized. This also holds true for all other languages that I know.
I am wondering if it would be a feasible to add the following capability to python's context manager interface:
┌── with CTX1 ──┐
╵               ╵
task_A --- task_B --- task_C
           ╷               ╷
           └── with CTX2 ──┘


Updated on 24/Oct to illustrated why asyncio could be used in this case and the author has already mentioned that he wants to utilise true threading in the comment section, so it is not the answer anyway:
import asyncio

lock_for_task1 = asyncio.Lock()
lock_for_task2 = asyncio.Lock()

async def mediator():
    while True:
        if conditionA:
            lock_for_task1.release()
        if conditionB:
            await lock_for_task1.acquire()
        if conditionB and conditionC:
            lock_for_task2.release()
        if conditionD:
           await lock_for_task2.acquire()
        asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            
async def task_protected_by_lock1():
    await lock_for_task1.acquire()
    print("task_protected_by_lock1")
    lock_for_task1.release()

async def task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2():
    await lock_for_task2.acquire()
    print("task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2")
    lock_for_task2.release()


I think here is where asyncio shines.
import asyncio

async def task_protected_by_lock1():
    print("task_protected_by_lock1")

async def task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2():
    print("task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2")

async def task_protected_by_lock2():
    print("task_protected_by_lock2")

async def f():
    try:
        await task_protected_by_lock1()
        await task_protected_by_lock1_and_lock2()
        await task_protected_by_lock2()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("sigint")
    except Exception as e:
        print("handle the exception you like")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(f())


I get your point that asyncio metigates race conditions by running everything in one single thread using a huge JS-like eventloop. However, since 3.13, GIL can be removed and it now makes actual difference in performance to run python in true multithreading.

if the function f() is running in one thread and other threads are racing for the same resource and you want to handle the locks manually, I would suggest you writing a mediator control thread to have full control over the resource allocation.

in this way, you could have a thread acting as a manager managing the context for other threads

You still need to protect the tasks with something lock-like if they perform any awaiting, which they probably are if you're using async. So you're in the same position, just with "async with" instead of "with".

@ArthurTacca since the tasks 1, 2, and 3 in f() are executed in one function and each of them is blocked by some locks, it is a typical use case of asyncio because it could leave other async tasks executing outside the f(). I think it gives you easier handling of resources in general. The main issue I think the question is how to handle to nesting lock which I do not show in my answer. I think the post author has concrete use mechanism of the locks which we do not know. If I were in such situation, I would use mediator to handle the locks.

@jediclustethp "I think the question is how to handle to nesting lock which I do not show in my answer" right, that's my point: the suggestion to use asyncio has nothing to do with the actual question.

@ArthurTacca I updated the answer, see if it could help you understand my suggestion

Your suggestion still doesn't address the core issue: how do you guarantee those locks are unlocked even if the code called while they're locked there's an exception? That's the point of the question. But there's no context managers or exception handler in sight in your code. Also, your mediator does locking but so do the tasks, which seems to be conflicting strategies. It just doesn't seem to be a coherent solution, regardless of whether you're using async.

the concept of my suggestion is to remove the nesting / interleaving locks nature in the function. in the code snippet, task1 is by itself not in the context of multiple locks which means it is no longer necessary to deal with the problems of nested context which I think is the main issue of the question. the author also shows he knows how to handle the exception already, and it is entirely up to the mediator and each task  to release the lock under exception but it is application dependent.
